# Imports within a class in pytest

Tags: python, inheritance, pytest

I have a project that is structured like this

```
Proj/
    SRC/
        Resources/
            Tests/
                test_MyClass.py
            MyClass.py
        Utils/
            MyUtlis.py
```

First of all, in order to create an instance of MyClass in the test class I have to use

```
import Proj.SRC.Resources.MyClass
```

Which is weird since all the other classes in Resources can just go SRC.Resources.class

But also, when I run Pytest I get an error around the imports in MyClass.py. So say MyClass imports MyUtils, I get an error like:

```
Proj\SRC\Resources\Tests\test_MyClass.py:2: in <module>
    from Proj.SRC.Resources import MyClass
Proj\SRC\Resources\MyClass.py:10: in <module>
    from SRC.Utils import MyUtils
E   ImportError: No module named SRC.Utils
```

Comment: add `__init__.py` and `import Proj.SRC.Resources.MyClass`?

Comment: I've tried it with __init__.py and without, doesn't seem to make a difference. But the import of MyClass is working, it's the classes that MyClass imports that don't seem to work.

Comment: `import Proj.SRC.Resources.MyClass.py` is already wrong and can't work. When importing a module defined in file `spam.py`, you only do `import spam` without the file extension. Also, show an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the issue.

Comment: Also, based on the project structure you provided, `MyClass` is not a module in `Resources` package, so `import Proj.SRC.Resources.MyClass` won't work - `import Proj.SRC.MyClass` should be the correct one.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it for clarity.